# Self-reference entity in Hibernate

Tags: hibernate, mapping, self-reference

I have an `Action` entity, that can have other `Action` objects as child in a bidirectional one-to-many relationship. 
The problem is that Hibernate outputs the following exception:

"Repeated column in mapping for collection: DbAction.childs column: actionId"

Below the code of the mapping:

```
<?xml version="1.0"?>
<!DOCTYPE hibernate-mapping PUBLIC
 "-//Hibernate/Hibernate Mapping DTD 3.0//EN"
 "http://hibernate.sourceforge.net/hibernate-mapping-3.0.dtd">
<hibernate-mapping>
 <class name="DbAction" table="actions">

  <id name="actionId" type="short" />
  <property not-null="true" name="value" type="string" />

  <set name="childs" table="action_action" cascade="all-delete-orphan">
   <key column="actionId" />
   <many-to-many column="actionId" unique="true" class="DbAction" />
  </set>

  <join table="action_action" inverse="true" optional="false">
   <key column="actionId" />
   <many-to-one name="parentAction" column="actionId" not-null="true" class="DbAction" />
  </join>
 </class>
</hibernate-mapping>
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

That's because you have `name="actionId"` declared more than once for the same table.

Comment: Because I'm referencing the same entity, so the ID field doesn't change.

Comment: Ops, i'm sorry you're right..i thought that it was mandatory to specify the same column names while creating relationships between entities, but it's not. So i resolved the problem by substituting the "actionId" value in the "key" element of the "set" element with "parentActionId", and then setting "parentActionId" in the "column" attribute of the "many-to-one" element.

Answer (score 1):

As *armandino* suggested, i tried to substitute the column name to "parentActionId", and it works:

```
<?xml version="1.0"?>
<!DOCTYPE hibernate-mapping PUBLIC
 "-//Hibernate/Hibernate Mapping DTD 3.0//EN"
 "http://hibernate.sourceforge.net/hibernate-mapping-3.0.dtd">
<hibernate-mapping>
 <class name="DbAction" table="actions">

  <id name="actionId" type="short" />
  <property not-null="true" name="value" type="string" />

  <set name="childs" table="action_action" cascade="all-delete-orphan">
   <key column="parentActionId" />
   <many-to-many column="actionId" unique="true" class="DbAction" />
  </set>

  <join table="action_action" inverse="true" optional="false">
   <key column="actionId" />
   <many-to-one name="parentAction" column="parentActionId" not-null="true" class="DbAction" />
  </join>
 </class>
</hibernate-mapping>
```